# ABI compatibility between gcc 7.1 and gcc 11.1

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++20, abi

I have a static library compiled with gcc 7.1 and I'm wondering if I can link it to a process compiled with gcc 11.1 c++20.

I have a c++ library compiled with gcc 7.1 c++17 and I'm wondering if I can link it to a process compiled with gcc 11.1 c++20.

Comment: Did you try it? Shouldn't the linker complain if it is not binary compatible? static or dynamic linking?

Comment: Try it. If it fails, search the web for the error messages. If that doesn't work, extract a [mcve]. If you still can't find an answer, ask here. Asking a yes/no question about something which you could easily answer yourself isn't good.

Comment: It can compile and work but it may generate a disaster !!

Comment: AFAIK there are no ABI compatibility guarantees. Recompile the library with the new compiler.

Comment: Code librarian Titus Winters would say "compile everything — ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING — with the same flags, at the same time, with the same compiler, or fear the wrath of the ODR gods."