# Boost library vs project flags

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

Is it safe to build boost with default flags and link it to an application using c++20 standard.
Boost uses c++11 as default option.
I'm using gcc 11.1

Comment: It depends, some libraries might have a different ABI under different language versions

Comment: Is it the case for boost?

Comment: It can be, you'll need to study the documentation for each library

Comment: How is this question different than [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746878/is-it-safe-to-link-c17-c14-and-c11-objects) of [the question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956597/abi-compatibility-between-gcc-7-1-and-gcc-11-1)? (In fact, this question looks like a better match to that duplicate than what you asked yesterday, since yesterday's question brought in different compiler versions.)

Comment: If you want to ask something new, maybe you would be interested in asking how you could specify a language standard when building Boost? (I'd also suggest mentioning at least one of the libraries for which you need something compiled, since much of Boost is header-only.)

Comment: I want to build boost thread. isn't dangerous to use c++ 11 compiled lib with application code compiled with c++20